# How i can acquire temperature by Thermo couple on Labview

Tags: labview

every one i have knowledge about DAQ but my main question is which type of Thermo couple i used for NI DAQ devices and i there some link to buy it online,

waiting for your kind Response

Answer (score 0):

You can read about thermocouple types [here](https://www.thermocoupleinfo.com/). [These](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/select/c-series-temperature-input-module) are all the current temp-sensing module options. You'll have to dig into documentation here to determine which type of thermocouple will be required.